# How to change background on safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried putting a color on the body, it didn't work. The first screen is as it is now, the second is as it should be.

[image]
[image]

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(87.52deg, #2570b5 21.14%, #67deee 91.14%) !important;
}
```

Solved the problem, the gradient is not supported.

Comment: what did you do? does it work on other browsers?

Comment: On the first screen is my site, I just set the background-color, but it is displayed only on the PC. The second screen is a random site where this problem is solved

Comment: It works in all browsers, I only noticed this in Safari, on iphone

Comment: can you show relevant code ... you've tagged javascript, html and css ... so, do you set the background colour using javascript, inline style in html, or css? Please show **exactly** what you are doing

Comment: seriously - why do we need the images displayed inline @Yai

Comment: I added the code, as I said above - I just put the background

Comment: looks correct syntax - try `background-image` instead or even add `!important` - as we can't see ALL your CSS :p

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work on safari

```
body {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(87.52deg,rgb(37, 112, 181)), color-stop(21.14%,rgb(103, 222, 238)), color-stop(91.14%));
}
```